# How to decompose Arabic letter?

Tags: swift, string, unicode, arabic

I need to decompose an Arabic word into its consonants and vowels. For instance, "ضَرَبَ" has three consonants and three vowels and therefore I would like its length to be  6 instead of 3. However:

```
let t = "ضَرَبَ"
let ud = t.decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping
print("ud Length = \(ud.count)")
```

I get 3 instead of 6... How to decompose this string into the following array:

```
"\u{0636}\u{064e}\u{0631}\u{064e}\u{0628}\u{064e}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your goal here is to consider Unicode code points rather than a collection of Swift `Character` (i.e. extended grapheme clusters), after applying normalization. You can do that with `.unicodeScalars`:

```
print("ud Length = \(ud.unicodeScalars.count)")  // ud Length = 6
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Keep in mind that this is not just "consonants and vowels." Things like shaddah and nunation will also be code points after normalization (I assume that's a benefit for your use case; just something to keep in mind).

Your question about "decompose this string into the following array" is somewhat misguided. The example you give is a String, not an Array. But importantly, it is **the same String as `t`**. (Check it with `==`.) If you want an Array of UnicodeScalars, however, that would be `Array(ud.unicodeScalars)`.

Comment: Aside: In Unicode's terminology, characters correspond 1:1 with code points, and "Unicode scalar value" is a synonym for code point. What `ud.count` appears to be returning is what Unicode refers to as grapheme clusters.

Comment: Correct, but this is Swift, which is why I capitalized "Characters." This refers to the type `Character`, which in Swift is an extended grapheme cluster. I'll edit to avoid confusing non-Swift developers. Swift also uses the word "Unicode scalars" for what everyone else calls "code points" (or "characters"). Swift's Unicode support is absolutely top-notch (best I've seen in any language), but it does use a slightly nonstandard vocabulary. This makes Swift easier ("Character" is usually the thing the programmer should be using, so has a simple name), but can be confusing to more expert devs.